# ubuntu in vagrant, apt-get update failed

Tags: apt, vagrant

I set a vagrant vm, and try to `apt-get update`,get this

```
Fetched 1,358 kB in 1min 19s (17.1 kB/s)                                       
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
```

After searching the topic, all the solution don't work.I'm not sure whether is about vagrant or Ubuntu itself.